# Migrating Fixtures to Django Test Database

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to use a custom database for my tests. I can ensure this by a custom setting file for tests.

How can I export fixtures to this test database? (e.g. superuser for tests or other test related database exports) I'm ready to apply other solutions instead of fixtures if fixtures are not applicable to second custom database.

Here's my custom setting file for testing: (settings/test.py)

```
from defaults import *

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'my_test_db',
    }
}
```

Here's how I run the tests:

```
python manage.py test --settings=settings.test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify a separate test database if you just want to load fixtures for your tests.
Django will automatically create [a separate blank test database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database) for testing.

If you want to reuse some fixtures based on your development or production database, you can try to [dump the database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata), here is an example command for dumping data in yaml format. JSON format is also supported.:

```
pip install pyyaml

python manage.py dumpdata --format=yaml > /foo_app/fixtures/dump_file.yaml
```

In your setting, you can add a list of fixture dir like:

```
FIXTURE_DIRS = ('/foo_app/fixtures/',)
```

In your testing scripts, you can specify which fixture file shall be used for a TestCase class, like the following:

```
class FooAppTest(TestCase):
    """
    Test class for getting Foo
    """

    fixtures = ['dump_file.yaml']
```

After setting up like the above, your tests for that class will load the fixture file(with the users or other objects populated for testing).

You can find more details about creating and loading fixtures [in the documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading)

Comment: How do you deal with these fixtures when the database has been migrated?